# Redirecting to previous page using Authguard

Tags: angular

I want to implement the redirection functionality where if user is loggin then user needs to go to previous page
ex... Page A ----> Login (susccess)
'
PageA<------
I have done this by implementing the router event subscribe method but the problem is router event doesnt fire when page is loaded hence my manager suggested me to go with authguard where i am getting the URL of previous page but how to implement it, and once i get the previous URL, i am storing and dispatching the URL from login to further position, basically i need the previous URL on login component.

Below is the sample auth guard :

```js
import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Router,
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
} from '@angular/router';

import {
  LocalStorageService
} from 'ngx-webstorage';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  userSessionId: string | null = null;
  URLPath: string | undefined;
  constructor(private router: Router, private storage: LocalStorageService) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {


    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url

    this.URLPath = this.router.url.substring(
      0,
      this.router.url.lastIndexOf('/')
    );
    debugger
    console.log(state.url, "previous **************url*********");
    this.router.navigate([this.URLPath + '/login'], {
      queryParams: {
        returnUrl: state.url
      },
    });
    return false;
  }
}
```

In the above console getting the previous URL the first issue i am facing is auth guard is using can activate state where it will be accessed only for few pages which needs the session token
same goes with CANLoad.

Below is the routing.ts

```js
{
  path: 'services',
  loadChildren: () =>
    import ('../services/services.module').then((m) => m.ServicesModule),
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
}, {
  path: 'select-employee/:serviceId',
  loadChildren: () =>
    import ('../employee/employee.module').then((m) => m.EmployeeModule),
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
}, {
  path: 'appointments',
  loadChildren: () =>
    import ('../appointments/appointments.module').then(
      (m) => m.AppointmentsModule
    ),
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
}, {
  path: 'review',
  loadChildren: () =>
    import ('../review/review.module').then((m) => m.ReviewModule),
  canLoad: [CanLoadReviewGuard],
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
}, {
  path: 'bookings',
  loadChildren: () =>
    import ('../bookings/bookings.module').then((m) => m.BookingsModule)
}, {
  path: 'login',
  loadChildren: () =>
    import ('src/app/authentication/login/login.module').then((m) => m.LoginModule)
},
```

in the above for few components already auth guard is implemented i guess i cant create new one
and if so i implement the authguard how to get the state.url in login component?

Please help me got stuck in this issue since long

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the previous URL as "returnURL" query param to the login route. You will see this in the browser addressbar.

Here is an extract from your code.

```
this.router.navigate([this.URLPath + '/login'], {
      queryParams: {
        returnUrl: state.url
      },
    });
```

In the login component you can access the query param

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
....
this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] 
}
```

Once login is successful you can use this returnUrl to navigate

```
this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
```

Comment: this.router.navigate([this.URLPath + '/login'], {
      queryParams: {
        returnUrl: state.url
      },
    });

If i use /login then it is going to login page with return url but i dont want to go to login until i click on login page, and once i go to login i should be able to access the previous url

Comment: Any other solutions?

Comment: In that case, you will have to use dialog to tell user that session has timed out and login now. But still you will have to navigate to login using returnUrl. Even in the current code state.url is pointing to the previous URL, it is passed as param to the login component. You can retrieve it from the query params.

Comment: i can retrieve it from login but i cant directly redirect to login unless in click on login option from any page

Comment: In the current AuthGuard code, I don't see any check if the user is logged in or not. It is always taking use to the login page. Is this the problem?